# Should line art in Illustrator be drawn at 100% zoom?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm doing line art for a sketch that I already created in Photoshop. When I imported the drawing into Illustrator and zoomed it to 100%, I noticed that it was a lot smaller than how it appeared in Photoshop. I did the lines for one of the characters so far while zoomed in to about 200% since 100% made it difficult to see all the little details. However, when I zoomed back out, the lines appeared thick and jumbled together. You can see what I mean below. Am I supposed to do the line art while the document is zoomed at 100%? How am I supposed to see all the smaller details? Basically, I want the Illustrator lines to look almost identical to the Photoshop lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Draw at whatever scale you like and you feel conformable with.**

Since art created in Illustrator is vector in nature, it can be rescaled when you are done to whatever size you need without any quality loss.

Typically, when I place something in AI for tracing, I enlarge it to 200% or more in Illustrator, then manually trace it. I do *not* zoom in. I enlarge the placed image.

You may feel your paths are "thick and jumbled together" depending upon the stroke weights and the pixel density of your monitor. If all the strokes are less than 1pt in size, when zoomed out, the monitor has no choice but to use the smallest unit it can to display them - 1 pixel. That may make paths *look* thicker primarily due to anti-aliasing for display. Also a good reason to work larger if you can.

Comment: Aha, that last bit makes perfect sense. The strokes are all less than 1pt. But what's the difference between enlarging the image to 200% and zooming in 200%? Would the results be different? I suppose if I enlarge the placed image, I can work with larger pixel brushes. Is that what you mean?

Comment: If you enlarge the image 200% you can draw with 1pt strokes.. or there about. For me, that tends to give a better overall impression of the final piece. In addition, it makes adding minute details sooooo much easier. I can always scale strokes down afterwards if necessary.

Comment: I don't always *calculate* 200%.. I just use Free Transform to enlarge the placed image to where I'm comfortable working. -- also for print.. anything less than 0.25pt for a stroke weight may get lost or increased to 0.25pt upon output.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tips, Scott!